# (<type 'exceptions.ValueError'>, ValueError('need more than 1 value to unpack',), <traceback object at 0x7f24dea1a0e0>) NULL NULL NULL

Tags: python, hive, mapr

I have HIVE table like this in MapR.

[image]

data was separated with commas at back end. I am trying to use custom map reduce in using python. Here is the python code.

```
import sys
import datetime
try:
    for line in sys.stdin:
        line = line.strip()
        userid, movieid, rating, unixtime = line.split(',')
        weekday = datetime.datetime.fromtimestamp(float(unixtime)).isoweekday()
        print ','.join([userid, movieid, rating, unixtime, str(weekday)])
except:
    print sys.exc_info()
```

I have added python script using `add File`, submitted query like this

```
select TRANSFORM (userid,movieid,rating,unixtime) using 'python mod.py' as (userid,movieid,rating,weekday) from u_data;
```

Error that i am getting here is

```
(<type 'exceptions.ValueError'>, ValueError('need more than 1 value to unpack',), <traceback object at 0x7f24dea1a0e0>) NULL    NULL  NULL
```

Why am i getting this error?

Comment: You should remove the try/except and let the full exception (and traceback) be printed.

Comment: I did try that, here is the stacktrace `Caused by: org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.metadata.HiveException: [Error 20003]: An error occurred when trying to close the Operator running your custom script` @RushyPanchal

Comment: I'd guess you're getting an empty line somewhere in your input (maybe at the end, if there's an extra newline after the last row of data). Adding `if not line: continue` to your loop (just after `strip`) would let you skip over blank lines.

Answer (score 0):

The only line in your code that could give you that error is this one:

```
userid, movieid, rating, unixtime = line.split(',')
```

So it's complaining that there aren't enough values to unpack, which means there aren't any commas in the line. Try printing the line before processing it; that way you will easily be able to tell what data you are getting and how you need to process it.

Comment: Here is the part of log, `Stage-Stage-1: Map: 1   Cumulative CPU: 1.01 sec   MAPRFS Read: 0 MAPRFS Write: 0 SUCCESS
Total MapReduce CPU Time Spent: 1 seconds 10 msec
OK
1       101     8       1369721454
(<type 'exceptions.ValueError'>, ValueError('need more than 1 value to unpack',), <traceback object at 0x7f87a6881050>) NULL    NULL  NULL
Time taken: 22.7 seconds, Fetched: 2 row(s)`

Comment: So, yes? No commas in that line, at least. Clearly you are not getting what you expect. So figure out what you're getting and write code to deal with that, instead of what you have now.

Comment: It is able to display 4 columns in the line, here is the link [link](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uFfXf.png) @kindall

Comment: Still no commas though.

Comment: as it is showing line as tab delimited, I have split the line with `\t` here is the python [code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7j9jP.png) and here is the [query](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OMJIH.png) execution . So, where am i going wrong here.